# Issue with Java Discord.js Modmail System

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I have been trying to make a discord ModMail system on my bot and there is an error that I can't understand my code is below:

```
client.on('message', message => {
    if (message.author.bot || !message.content.startsWith(prefix)) return;
    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/+ /)

    if (!message.channel.name.includes('modmail')) {
        return;
    } else {
        if (isNaN(args[0])) {
            return message.channel.send('Sorry but that is not a valid user')
        }
        let storage = message.guild.members.cache;
        let memberId = storage.find(member => member.id.toLowerCase() === args[0]);

        if (memberId) {
            const msg = message.content.slice(args[0].length + prefix.length).split(" ").join(" ");
            let embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setThumnail(message.author.displayAvatarURL())
            .setDescription(`<@${message.author.id}>\n------------\n${msg}`)
            .setColor('#599cff')
            .setFooter('ModMail System')
            .setTimestamp();
            client.users.fetch(args[0]).then(user => user.send(embed).catch(err => console.log(err)));

            message.channel.send('Your message was sent to the staff team! Please be patient for your reply.')
        } else {
            return message.channel.send('Could not find the user sorry.');
        }
    }
});

client.on('message', message => {
    var msg = message.content;
    var n = message.author.username;

    if (message.channel.type === 'dm') {
        if (message.author.bot) return;

        let blacklisted = ['word1', 'word2']

        let foundInText = false;
        for (var i in blacklisted) {
            if (message.content.toLowerCase().includes(blacklisted[i].toLowerCase())) foundInText = true;
        }

        if (foundInText) {
            return message.channel.send('Please do not use foul language in the message. (if you must please cover it with symbols *not letters*)');
        }

        message.channel.send('Your message was sent to the staff team! Please be patient for your reply.');
        const mailMessage = `${message.author.id} ${msg}`

        client.channels.fetch('795031406442315816').then(user => user.send(mailMessage).catch(err => console.log(err)));
    }
});
```

The error that is shown is:
SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /+ /: Nothing to repeat

This has been confusing me for a while (I am new to code) please if you know how to fix this it would help a lot thank you.

Comment: You also have a typo in `setThumbnail`.

Answer (score 0):

I think the error is because there is a problem here:

```js
const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/+ /)
```

If you change `.split(/+ /)` to `.split(' ')` or `.split(/ /)` it would work.